# My 1 year 3 months daughter wakes up crying suddenly at night.

Tags: sleep

My 1 year 3 months daughter wakes up crying suddenly at night. 
I try medicine for stomach pain, leg pain, check the AC (As it is hot summer) but this happens every day from last one month.
Actually before 20-25 days she was suffering from acute diarrhea and doctor said it is due to virus. She had severe rashes also at that time. Now everything is cured. this is just for extra information if this has any relation with this sleep problem. Also after that she is still having problem related to motion. some of the days she gets constipation.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Are you asking for reasons why she may wake up suddenly in the middle of the night aside from previous medical reasons? Have you consulted your pediatrician regarding a possible link between constipation and waking at night?

Comment: My 2 1/2 year old still wakes up crying every night. It's pretty easy to get her back to sleep but it has been like this for both my girls for years. Their behavior never suggests pain. More like waking up and no parent around. I can only hope she grows out of it like my 4 year old has. Prepare yourself for the possibility it's just a phase that could take years to outgrow.